# Django 1.8 request.user is removed

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am using django 1.8 along with mongoengine and a custom Middleware that is supposed to add a user and a toked to a django request.

These two are passed in the header of the request.

The middleware class is the following :

```
from models import MongoToken

class TokenAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION" not in request.META:
                return
        tokenkey = get_authorization_header(request).split()[1]
        token = MongoToken.objects.get(key=tokenkey)
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.META.get("HTTP_USERNAME"))
        if token.key == tokenkey and token.user.is_active:
            request.user = user
            request.token = tokenkey
```

I also put this in my `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` block of the settings.py files:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.MongoAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'myproject.middleware.TokenAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

And when the considered view is reached, my token is here because thanks to the header params but the user is Null.
Then I am wondering if I did something wrong with this because it does not work.

Thank you for your help.

Alex.